# Menu bar disappeard in LibreOffice, Waterfox after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice, xfce

After upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, both LibreOffice and Waterfox no longer have menu bars.  I am using XFCE4 as my desktop environment.  I have seen that this problem pops up from time to time and is usually fixed as a bug, or the solutions provided do not seem applicable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get my LibreOffice menu bar back by uninstalling the libreoffice-gtk* packages.

Waterfox-classic is still a no go.

Answer (score 0):

In the firefox meu, look for "Customize". In the "Customize Firefox" tab that appears, locate the "Toolbars" buttom at the bottom. Click it, and set the checkmark before "Menu bar" to have a permanent display of the menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only option under "Toolbars" is "Bookmark Toolbar".

Comment: Strange. It  is there in my version under Ubuntu 20.04, which is the default version: 76.0.1